# Order of InsertManyResult.inserted_ids in case of unordered bulk insert

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm wondering if the order of ids of `InsertManyResult.inserted_ids` returned by an **un-ordered** bulk insert is consistent with the order of the input array? i.e that the first id from `InsertManyResult.inserted_ids` corresponds to the id of the first item of the input array

In fact, if I consider the following example:

```py
from pymongo import *

connection = MongoClient()

users = [{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Bob'}, {'name': 'Hulk'}]
r = connection.testdb.user.insert_many(users, ordered=False)

print(r.inserted_ids)
print(users)
```

which prints the following:

```
[ObjectId('5d8bc14424c4cb24ac1d2334'),
 ObjectId('5d8bc14424c4cb24ac1d2335'),
 ObjectId('5d8bc14424c4cb24ac1d2336')]

[{'_id': ObjectId('5d8bc14424c4cb24ac1d2334'), 'name': 'John'},
 {'_id': ObjectId('5d8bc14424c4cb24ac1d2335'), 'name': 'Bob'},
 {'_id': ObjectId('5d8bc14424c4cb24ac1d2336'), 'name': 'Hulk'}]
```

In this simple example, the order is respected but due to the un-ordered nature of the insert, I'm wondering if it is always guaranteed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version: yes, except in rare situations**

Mongo _ids have ["a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch, a 5-byte random value, and a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value."](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid) Each of these parts will normally (but not always) be ordered (the timestamp & the counter) or constant (the 5 byte random value).

By default, mongo database drivers will generate `_id`s, so you can rely on those `_id`s having the same random value & generally rely on the timestamp & the counter moving forward. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/

#### The 4 byte timestamp

If you take a look at the [ObjectId generation code for node](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/88a77466be/lib/objectid.js#L251), you can see that it's using `Date` to generate the initial timestamp portion of the ObjectId & `Date` can go backwards when the clock updates. I'd assume it's doing a similar thing on all of the drivers, so they'd all likely have out-of-order _ids if you're doing an insert at the same time that the clock updates.

From testing, it seems like even if you [force server (i.e. database) generated ids](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html), `insertMany` with `ordered=false` will still preserve the _id ordering. Mongo doesn't do any sort of smearing on clock updates, so if there are any clock updates on the server that Mongo is running on, _ids might also be out of the order in the insertion array.

#### The 5 byte random value

This should remain constant, but if you're having mongo (rather than the driver) generate the _ids & there's a failover, I believe it will change. I'm unsure how that'd interact with inserts.

#### The 3 byte counter

The 3 byte counter will reset after counting 2^24 (~16 million) documents. That means that if your driver (if _ids are being generated there) or mongo (if _ids are being generated there), reaches that point, documents inserted during that second in a bulk insert (either ordered or unordered) won't be ordered by _id.

#### Mongo's `recordId`

Internally, mongo uses a [`recordId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.showRecordId/) rather than _id as its primary key. If you you do an unordered insert and look at the `recordIds`, `_ids` will be in the order that they were in the insertion array, but `recordIds` will be ordered in the order that they were actually inserted and won't match the _id ordering.

```
  const conn = await mongodb.connect("mongodb://mongo:27017/");
  const db = conn.db("test");
  await db.collection("test").remove({});
  const toInsert = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    toInsert.push({i})
  }
  await db.collection("test").insertMany(toInsert, {ordered: false, forceServerObjectId: true});
  const results = await db.collection("test").find({}).showRecordId(true).sort({_id: 1}).toArray();
  let prev;
  for (const result of results) {
    if (prev) {
      // this will throw because recordids are not ordered as expected
      assert(prev < result.$recordId)
    }
    prev = result.$recordId;
  }
```

Comment: @bagerard, I added a few details about the counter portion of the _id. It's probably not super relevant to you, but I figured I'd mention it!